# on calculating the complexity of algorithm from clrs book

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
                                //Number of times 
for j=2 to A.length`          //n
    key = A[j]      //n-1
    i=j-1         //n-1
    while i>0 and A[i]>key    //summation of j from 2 to n of t(j) 
       A[i+1]= A[i]        //summation from j from 2 to n of t(j)-1
       i=i-1               //ditto
    A[i+1]=key   //n-1
```

What I don't understand is why the number of time in the first for one is n instead of n-1? And also in the summation why it is from t(j) vs t(j)-1 in the while loop. I know it really does not matter since theyre constants but it still is confusing to me. Thanks! This is from the CLRS algorithm textbook.Insertion sort.

Comment: You *know* it doesn't matter since it doesn't change the asymptotic complexity, but you are still confused about it? I don't get that - if you *know* why, how can you be confused?

Comment: I want to know how the analysis works. if you can explain, please do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a for-loop such as:

```
for(int j = 2; j < 4; j++) {}
```

The condition `j < 4` needs to be tested 3 times: when j=2, j=3, and j=4. The loop body will only run 2 times: when j=2, and j=3. The final 'false' condition counts as an extra test.